# Matlab: Creating customized numeric data types

Tags: matlab, numeric, data-modeling, customization

Please, does anyone know how create your own  numeric data types in Matlab? I would like to do the numeric data type with six data parts one for sign, other for mantisa, for exponent, for number of bits for sign data part (It  always be one bit), for number of bits to store the mantisa data and for number of bits to store the exponent.
So you can specifty the number of bits to store the numeric data part dedicate to the exponent or the mantisa.
With this data type if would be possible to modell all data types of the IEEE 754 and whatever not standar numeric data type.
By the way this question is related with  ["Development of a specific hardware architecture for a particular algorithm"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14206/development-of-a-specific-hardware-architecture-for-a-particular-algorithm)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any reason why the datatypes in Matlab are insufficient for what you want to do?  If you could give us more background on why you want to do this we may be able to suggest a built-in Matlab datatype.  But as far as I know there is no way to do something like this without using C-mex extensions.

Comment: @JudoWill: I want to modell digital architectures with different formats for representing floating point in order to measure the error I get from every one of them to compare their numeric accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Some obvious solutions:

1. Just use an array with 6 members to represent each number of one of your custom types.
2. Use a structure so that you can refer to the parts of a number by name.
3. Use Matlab's object-oriented programming facilities.

The last of these options is probably the best, allowing you to define operations on your custom types which respect the rules for the types.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be use the **Fixed-Point** toolbox:

> The toolbox enables you to create the following types of objects:

```
* fi — Defines a fixed-point numeric object in the MATLAB workspace. Each fi object is composed of value data, a fimath object, and a numerictype object.
* fimath — Governs how overloaded arithmetic operators work with fi objects
* fipref — Defines the display, logging, and data type override preferences of fi objects
* numerictype — Defines the data type and scaling attributes of fi objects
* quantizer — Quantizes data sets
```

Comment: I see from your other question that, while you think this is the right way to go, you are still asking for very basic help.  The quality of answer you get on SO is in direct proportion to the quality of question.  If you demonstrate that you have made a serious attempt to solve your own problems then help will come.  If you fail to demonstrate that, well, it won't.